# wrong account number in admob

Tags: admob, payment

I found that I enter the bank card number in admob payment details instead of account number . The first payment is already sent ,but I did not get the money in my account.What I should do ? can I get my money back

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **customer support** question. [Why customer support questions are off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) .